# How to change the name of committed commit message on Github?

Tags: github, version-control

### Changing

I formatted some code and typed on Github the message **formatting** and clicked **commit changes**.

Is there a way to rename this commit from **formatting** to **fmtg** ?

*committed* - in the sense of not pushing the repo with git but editing code from Github 'level' and commit changes

### Create new & delete second to last commit

Or there is only a way to create new commit?

#### created

So I created a new commit message **fmtg** with dumb deletion of comma `.` in comment

Comment: I think you are looking for: [git commit --amend](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-commit-message/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the command below:

```
git commit --amend
```